# Conditions for the differentiation of Fourier Transform of a function.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-transform

Suppose $\varphi(t)$ is smooth on $\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)=\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \varphi(t) e^{-2\pi ixt}dt$ is the Fourier Transform of $\varphi(t)$. Then Inverse Fourier Transform is given by:
\begin{equation}
\varphi(t)=\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-2\pi ixt}dx
\end{equation}
My question is what should be the conditions on $f(x)$ so that I can differentiate $\varphi(t)$?
Can I differentiate to get:
\begin{equation*}
\varphi'(t)=(-2\pi i)\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf(x) e^{-2\pi ixt}dx
\end{equation*}

Comment: Integrability of $xf(x)$ is a sufficient condition.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy If I have to differentiate again then integrability of $x^2f(x)$ would be sufficient and son, right? What would be the good reference related to it?

Comment: You are right and you get these by an application of DCT.

Comment: The sufficient condition is that $\lim_{A,B \to \infty} \int_{-A}^B x f(x) e^{-2i \pi xt}dx$ converges uniformly for $t \in U$, so that $\int_b^c \lim_{A,B \to \infty} \int_{-A}^B (-2i \pi x) f(x) e^{-2i \pi xt}dxdt=\lim_{A,B \to \infty} \int_{-A}^B   f(x) (\int_b^c (-2i \pi x) e^{-2i \pi xt}dt)dx$ $=\lim_{A,B \to \infty} \int_{-A}^B   f(x) ( e^{-2i \pi cx}- e^{-2i \pi bx})dx=\varphi(c)-\varphi(b)$ which implies that $\varphi'(c) = \lim_{A,B \to \infty} \int_{-A}^B x f(x) e^{-2i \pi xt}dx$ which is then continuous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fundamental theorem in the Lebesgue Theory of Integration :

Let ${\displaystyle X}$ be an open subset of ${\displaystyle \mathbf {R} }$, and ${\displaystyle \Omega }$ be a measure space. Suppose ${\displaystyle f\colon X\times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbf {R} }$ satisfies the following conditions:

${\displaystyle f(x,\omega )}$ is a Lebesgue-integrable function of ${\displaystyle \omega }$ for each ${\displaystyle x\in X}$.
For almost all ${\displaystyle \omega \in \Omega }$, the derivative ${\displaystyle f_{x}}$ exists for all ${\displaystyle x\in X}$.
There is an integrable function ${\displaystyle \theta \colon \Omega \rightarrow \mathbf {R} }$ such that ${\displaystyle |f_{x}(x,\omega )|\leq \theta (\omega )}$ for all ${\displaystyle x\in X}$ and almost every ${\displaystyle \omega \in \Omega }$.
Then by the Dominated convergence theorem for all ${\displaystyle x\in X}$,
${\displaystyle {\frac {d}{dx}}\int _{\Omega }f(x,\omega )\,d\omega =\int _{\Omega }f_{x}(x,\omega )\,d\omega .}$

Comment: Can you please provide me reference to this result?

Comment: Any measure theory book like Follan : Real analysis and modern techniques, or simply visit wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule,
by scrolling down you'll see the measure theoretic statement