# Differentiating Fourier Transform of a Schwarz function

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-transform, schwartz-space

My question is related to this question [Conditions for the differentiation of Fourier Transform of a function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3045851/conditions-for-the-differentiation-of-fourier-transform-of-a-function) Suppose my function $f(x)$ is from a Schwarz function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space , since Fourier transform is an automorphism on the space of Schwarz space, we have that $\varphi(t)$ is also in Schwarz space.

This means $\varphi(t)$ is smooth and I can naturally differentiate under the integral sign without invoking a Leibnitz rule in measure space given in the first link I have provided?

In particular, my $f(x)$ is bounded smooth function with compact support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Since $\varphi$ is a Schwartz function, this means that all $x^n \varphi^{(m)}$ are in $L^1(\Bbb R)$ and we can apply the Dominated convergence theorem just fine.

**Edit**: To add more details, let's consider 
$$
\frac d{dx}[x^2\varphi(x)] = 2x\varphi(x) + x^2\varphi'(x)
$$
which is bounded on $\Bbb R$ by the fact that $\varphi$ is Schwartz, says $\frac d{dx}[x^2\varphi(x)]\le M$. Thus
$$
|(x+h)^2\varphi(x+h) - x^2\varphi(x)| \le hM
$$
by the mean value theorem (wlog $h>0$), i.e.
$$
\left|\left(1+\frac hx\right)^2\varphi(x+h) - \varphi(x)\right| \le \frac {hM}{x^2}
$$
for large $|x|$. Thus
$$\begin{align}
|\varphi(x+h) - \varphi(x)| &\le  \left|\varphi(x+h) - \left(1+\frac hx\right)^2\varphi(x+h)\right| + \left|\left(1+\frac hx\right)^2\varphi(x+h) - \varphi(x)\right| \\
&\le \frac {hC}{x^2} + \frac {hM}{x^2}.
\end{align}$$
where $C$ can be obtained from the fact that $\varphi$ is Schwartz. Provide that $h<1$, we have
$$\begin{align}
\frac {|\varphi(x+h) - \varphi(x)|}h &\le \frac {C}{x^2} + \frac {M}{x^2}
\end{align}$$
 This shows that the difference quotient $\frac {|\varphi(x+h) - \varphi(x)|}h$ is bounded above (for small $h$) by an $L^1(\Bbb R)$ function. Hence we may apply the Dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Thank you @BigbearZzz

Comment: @ersh I added some details I left out earlier. I was sleepy back then.

Comment: Thanks for the details.